# MongoDB Finding duplicates sharing multiple fields using MapReduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, duplicates

I am trying to find duplicates in a Mongo version 2.4 database that is being used for production and therefore cannot be updated. Since aggregate does not exist in 2.4, **I cannot use the aggregate pipeline** to find duplicates, therefore I am trying to find a solution using MapReduce.

I have tried the following set of map, reduce, and finalize functions, through MongoVUE's Map Reduce interface, and they returned nothing after running for less than a second on a 3,000,000 record collection that definitely has duplicates on the indicated fields. Obviously something went wrong, but MongoVUE did not show any error messages or helpful indications.

```
function Map() {
  emit(
    {name: this.name, LocationId: this.LocationId, 
     version: this.version},
    {count:1, ScrapeDate: this.ScrapeDate}
  );
}

function Reduce(key, values) {
  var reduced = {count:0, ScrapeDate:''2000-01-01''};
  values.forEach(function(val) {
    reduced.count      += val.count;
    if (reduced.ScrapeDate.localeCompare(val.ScrapeDate) < 0)
      reduced.ScrapeDate=val.ScrapeDate;
  });

  return reduced;
  return values[0];
}

function Finalize(key, reduced) {
  if (reduced.count > 1)
    return reduced;
}
```

I just need to find any instance of multiple records that share the same `name`, `LocationId`, and `version`, and ideally display the most recent `ScrapeDate` of such a record.

Answer (score 2):

Your map-reduce code worked without any issues, though for a very small dataset. I think `return values[0];` in the reduce function would be a copy paste error. You could try the same through the mongo shell.

> *Since aggregate does not exist in 2.4, I cannot use the aggregate pipeline to find duplicates, therefore I am trying to find a solution
>   using MapReduce.*

You got it wrong here, `db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options)` was introduced in the `version 2.2`.

Here is how it could be done with the `aggregation` framework, but it would not be preferred since your dataset is very huge, and the `$sort` operator has memory limit of 10% of RAM, in v2.4.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 [
   // sort the records, based on the 'ScrapeDate' field, in descending order.
   {$sort:{"ScrapeDate":-1}},

   // group by the key fields, and take the 'ScrapeDate' of the first document,
   // Since it is in sorted order, the first document would contain the  
   // highest field value.
   {$group:{"_id":{"name":"$name","LocationId":"$LocationId","version":"$version"}
            ,"ScrapeDate":{$first:"$ScrapeDate"}
            ,"count":{$sum:1}}
           },

   // output only the group, having documents greater than 1.
   {$match:{"count":{$gt:1}}}
]
);
```

Coming to your Map-reduce functions, it ran without issues on my test data.

```
db.collection.insert({"name":"c","LocationId":1,"version":1,"ScrapeDate":"2000-01-01"});
db.collection.insert({"name":"c","LocationId":1,"version":1,"ScrapeDate":"2001-01-01"});
db.collection.insert({"name":"c","LocationId":1,"version":1,"ScrapeDate":"2002-01-01"});
db.collection.insert({"name":"d","LocationId":1,"version":1,"ScrapeDate":"2002-01-01"});
```

running the map-reduce,

```
db.collection.mapReduce(Map,Reduce,{out:{"inline":1},finalize:Finalize});
```

o/p:

```
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "name" : "c",
                                "LocationId" : 1,
                                "version" : 1
                        },
                        "value" : {
                                "count" : 3,
                                "ScrapeDate" : "2002-01-01"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "name" : "d",
                                "LocationId" : 1,
                                "version" : 1
                        },
                        "value" : null
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 0,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 4,
                "emit" : 4,
                "reduce" : 1,
                "output" : 2
        },
        "ok" : 1,
}
```

Notice that the output contains `value:null` for a record which doesn't have any duplicates.

This is due to your `finalize` function:

```
function Finalize(key, reduced) {
  if (reduced.count > 1)
    return reduced; // returned null by default for keys with single value,
                    // i.e count=1
}
```

The `finalize` function **do not** filter out keys. So you can't get only the keys that are duplicates. You will get all the keys, in the map-reduce output. In your finalize functions, you can just **not show their values**, which is what you are doing.